# Click a div to check / uncheck a checkbox

Tags: jquery

I applied the following code to make table rows check/uncheck a child checkbox when clicked. Now I discovered that when clicking the checkbox itself inside the row it doesent check. Could it be that it checks on click (standard function) and then the jquery picks up the click event and unchecks it? How can I fix this?

```
//check on div click
$("tr").live("click",function() {
    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");

    if( checkbox.attr("checked") == "" ){
        checkbox.attr("checked","true");
    } else {
        checkbox.attr("checked","");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that the click event is bubbling from the checkbox to the tr. Try adding this code as well:

```
$('tr input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**EDIT**

here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/GSqNv/

Comment: Just to clarify (if I understand correctly), clicking on the checkbox was causing the checkbox to check, then the event was passed up to the <div> element, causing the checkbox to uncheck (i.e. 2 checks)?

Comment: just so. if you had an alert in the function it would have fired twice

Comment: I had the same problem, I had put an console.log inside my parent click but it only fired once. Anyway, the e.stopPropagation() on the input fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check the target of the caller is not a checkbox

```
$("tr").live("click",function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:checkbox')) return;

    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");

    if( checkbox.attr("checked") == "" ){
       checkbox.attr("checked","true");
    } else {
       checkbox.attr("checked","");
    }
});
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/7Bze7/

The code above checks that the sender of the event is not a checkbox.

Comment: as of Feb. 2013 the live function has been depreciated for .click or .on, http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Besides the given solutions, isn't it better to just set the checkbox to the oposite state? For example:

```
var _current_state = checkbox.attr("checked");
checkbox.attr("checked") = !_current_state;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
return false;
```

As it is the same as entering both:

```
e.preventDefault(); 
e.stopPropagation();
```

I believe that is the go to - no?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you can do this simply by wrapping the div in the label. It doesn't work if the content in the div is what you are trying to change though, but it will check the checkbox.