# Click a li to check / uncheck a checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I applied the next code to make the li check/uncheck a child checkbox when clicked. The issue is that when clicking the checkbox itself it doesn't work. I already read [the post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083795/click-a-div-to-check-uncheck-a-checkbox) and tried to apply the `e.stopPropagation();` but still not working, any ideas?

```
 $('#columnList li').click(function(){
            var check = $(this).children();
            var checkVal = check.attr('value');
            var helper = $('.' + checkVal);
            console.log(helper);
            if(check.is(':checked')){
                check.attr('checked','');
                $.each(helper, function(i, e){
                    $(helper[i]).hide();
                });
            }else{
                check.attr('checked','checked');
                $.each(helper, function(i, e){
                    $(helper[i]).show();
                });
           } 
        });

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

HTML is a normal `ul` with a child checkbox. Nothing special about that.

Comment: Can you pust a jsfiddle with the case so that i can debug it ?!

Comment: Dosent make much sense... You should also use attr('checked', true/false) instead of checked and empty :) Tried using firebug on it, to see where i fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing -

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

to -

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to pass event to the function

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click( function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```