# clicking a child checkbox inside a parent li - the same as clicking adjacent text in the li

Tags: jquery

This must be quite simple (and probably a dupe), but I am not seeing it just now, and I have been looking!

I read (and attempted) more than just these approaches to my problem:

[Click a li to check / uncheck a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346115/click-a-li-to-check-uncheck-a-checkbox)

[Click a div to check / uncheck a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083795/click-a-div-to-check-uncheck-a-checkbox)

...but for the life of me, I seem unable to get the checkboxes in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/purushagovinda/7wZcS/8/

nor this SO-inspired derivative:

http://jsfiddle.net/purushagovinda/ysKLE/3/

...to behave as per my requirement:

I need that clicking on the text in a `<li>` will fire the toggle and highlight/un-highlight that text and check/uncheck that corresponding checkbox.  Clicking on a checkbox itself should behave the exact same as if the user had clicked the adjacent text instead of the checkbox.

What happens now is that clicking the checkbox does nothing.
I have tried playing (in the first fiddle) with permutations and combinations of these lines:

`if (target.is('input:checkbox')) return;`

&

```
   //e.preventDefault();
   //e.stopPropagation();
```

..but to no avail.

If anyone has any guidance for me, I'd appreciate it.

**---Edit:---**

**I should have mentioned that I need the toggle functions because I am doing a lot more stuff inside those functions that just toggling the `font-weight` and checking/unchecking the checkbox.**

Comment: Ok, edited my answer so you can do your cool stuff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `label` around the checkbox and the text, that will make clicking on the text activate the checkbox:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" title="Mesh Back" name="products_furniture_finishes" value="13548454609475">
  <span>Mesh Back</span>
</label>
```

On the click event of the checkboxes, set the style of the list item depending on the state of the checkbox:

```
$("#products_furniture_finishes_options :checkbox").click(function(e) {
  var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
  var li = $(this).closest('li');
  li.css("font-weight", checked ? "700" : "400");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/7wZcS/9/

Comment: please see my edit... i actually need the toggle functions to do more than just change the font-weight..

Comment: @govinda: Then just do that in the event handler. The `checked` variable contains the status of the checkbox, so that you can do different things depending on whether it is `true` or `false`.

Comment: yes. It just took me a few minutes to see what you did (I had at first neglected to see you switched focus onto the checkboxes' click (away from the click on the parent `<li>`).  Nice, clear, straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Tried different stuff and came up with this simple solution:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/oduguh/3/edit)**

CSS:

```
#products_furniture_finishes_options span{
  padding-left:28px;
  margin-left:-28px;  /* now cover the checkbox :) */
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#products_furniture_finishes_options > li").click(function(){

  var isChecked = $(this).find('input').is(':checked'); // returns a BOOLEAN value

  $(this).find('span').css({fontWeight: isChecked ? '400' : '700' });
  $(this).find('input').prop('checked', !isChecked);

  if( isChecked ){

       // do WOW stuff here (if checkbox was already checked)

  }else{

       // do other COOL stuff (if checkbox was OFF)

  }


});
```

Comment: could you add your edit to your jsbin?  I am finding odd results when I attempt to implement it.  I want to work with what you have posted...

Comment: @govinda there you go http://jsbin.com/oduguh/4/edit happy coding and lemme know if you got stuck

Comment: LOL.  I finally saw why your answer was working in your jsBin, but not in my script... because I had neglected to add/notice your CSS hack (i thougt, "how strange", and blew right past it)..  very clever. gave me a good laugh too.  :-)  I wish I could accept 2 answers.